# How to stop a WordPress Insert Post from creating a duplicate post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wp_insert_post function that will create a new post based on the inputted content of the current page. I thought that I had it so that it would not create a new post if a post with that title already existed, but it still does that. I've tried to use a null check but it hasn't worked. What should I do to fix this? Below is the relevant code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    $storyTitle=$_POST['storyTitle'];
    $storySummary=$_POST['storySummary'];
    $storyCategory=wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['storyCategory'] );
    $storyTags=$_POST['storyTags'];
    
    switch ($storyCategory) {
      case "Action":
        $storyCategory='3';
        break;
      case "Adventure":
        $storyCategory='4';
        break;
      case "Comedy":
        $storyCategory='5';
        break;
      case "Fanfiction":
        $storyCategory='6';
        break;
      case "Fantasy":
        $storyCategory='9';
        break;
      case "General Fiction":
        $storyCategory='12';
        break;
      case "Horror":
        $storyCategory='13';
        break;
      case "Mystery":
        $storyCategory='8';
        break;
      case "Poetry":
        $storyCategory='14';
        break;
      case "Romance":
        $storyCategory='7';
        break;
      case "Science Fiction":
        $storyCategory='10';
        break;
      case "Short Story":
        $storyCategory='11';
        break;
      default:
        $storyCategory=$_POST['storyCategory'];
    }
    
    $my_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['storyTitle'] ),
        'post_content'  => '',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => explode(',', $storyCategory),
        'tags_input' => explode(',', $storyTags)
);
    
    if ( get_page_by_title($storyTitle) == null ) {
        $post_id=wp_insert_post($my_post);
        if( $post_id ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_exists` function that checks post by title.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
{
    $storyTitle=$_POST['storyTitle'];
    $storySummary=$_POST['storySummary'];
    $storyCategory=wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['storyCategory'] );
    $storyTags=$_POST['storyTags'];
    
    switch ($storyCategory) {
      case "Action":
        $storyCategory='3';
        break;
      case "Adventure":
        $storyCategory='4';
        break;
      case "Comedy":
        $storyCategory='5';
        break;
      case "Fanfiction":
        $storyCategory='6';
        break;
      case "Fantasy":
        $storyCategory='9';
        break;
      case "General Fiction":
        $storyCategory='12';
        break;
      case "Horror":
        $storyCategory='13';
        break;
      case "Mystery":
        $storyCategory='8';
        break;
      case "Poetry":
        $storyCategory='14';
        break;
      case "Romance":
        $storyCategory='7';
        break;
      case "Science Fiction":
        $storyCategory='10';
        break;
      case "Short Story":
        $storyCategory='11';
        break;
      default:
        $storyCategory=$_POST['storyCategory'];
    }
    
    $my_post = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['storyTitle'] ),
        'post_content'  => '',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => explode(',', $storyCategory),
        'tags_input' => explode(',', $storyTags)
);
    
    if ( !post_exists( $storyTitle ) ) {
        $post_id=wp_insert_post($my_post);
        if( $post_id ){
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
    
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried it but every time I try it now it causes a critical error.